# Firebase - onAuthStateChanged 2 second delay. Add loading text/spinner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've created a to do list using React + firebase. After you user signs up and logins in they access to their to do lists, but when logged in if you refresh the page the onAuthStateChange check to see if they're logged in takes 2/3 seconds which means they see the login screen for a few seconds before seeing their to do list.

I was hoping there was a simple way to add in loading text/spinner for that 2/3 seconds they wait on refresh?

JS

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      toDo: [],
      loggedIn: false
    }

    this.addToDo = this.addToDo.bind(this);
    this.deleteToDo = this.deleteToDo.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        const dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${user.uid}`);
        dbRef.on("value", (res) => {
          const toDoArr = [];
          let toDoObj = res.val();
          for(let objKey in toDoObj) {
            toDoObj[objKey].key = objKey;
            toDoArr.push(toDoObj[objKey]);
          }
          this.setState({
            toDo: toDoArr,
            loggedIn: true
          });
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: false,
          toDo: []
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `loading` attribute as a part of state. Something like this

```
constructor() {
  // .....
  this.state = {
    loading: true,
    toDo: [],
    loggedIn: false
  }
}
```

loading from the state can be used in render this way

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading){
    return <Loading>My sweet spinner</Loading>;
  }
  // .... rest of the render 
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      name: ''
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        name: 'Stackoverflow'
      });
    }.bind(this), 2000);
  }
  render() {
    if(this.state.loading){
      return <div> Loading ... </div>;
    }
    return <div>This is {this.state.name}</div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```